# Why does my GFCI outlet trip when a vacuum is plugged in downstream?

Tags: electrical, gfci

Whenever I plug my vacuum into the downstream outlet the GFCI trips. I suspect the GFCI is at least 15 years old and the vacuum

Comment: Does anything else trip the circuit when plugged in "downstream"?

Comment: Could simply be that the vacuum is arcing and the GFCI is doing its job.

Comment: If you plug the vacuum into a kitchen or bathroom GFCI does it also trip?

Comment: Motor loads and both GFCI's and arc fault protected circuits don't play well together, brushed motors create arcs, all motors create inductive kickback, these spikes on the line both damage the electronics and or confuse the circuitry so they trip.

Answer (score 3):

GFCI breakers do wear out, but before you go out and buy a new one, do you have any other GFCI circuits in the house that you can try with the vacuum?  That would help isolate the issue to the breaker vs. the vacuum itself.